# Changing fragments with FragmentTransaction not working?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

When the user clicks an element in a `ListView` in one fragment, the listener is notified through an interface and it should change the fragment next to the menu.

My current code looks like this

```
Fragment f = null;

switch(fragmentId) {
    case 0:
        f = new xFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        f = new yFragment();
        break;
    ...
}

System.out.println(f.getClass().getName()); // Prints the name of the class correctly

FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, f);
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
transaction.commit();
```

When I select some option from the menu, this function in the activity that contains the fragment is called. It correctly prints the `fragmentId` and the name of the class is correct as told in the code sample.

However, the fragment isn't changed. I tried to replace the `f` variable in the `replace` method by `new xFragment()` but it didn't help.

The XML layout file looks this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/menuFragment"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="fi.peltoset.mikko.home.Navigation" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The LinearLayout `fragmentContainer` is the container for the fragments.

At startup I use the same code I showed above except I changed `replace` to `add` to add the right fragment when the application starts. This works fine.

What's wrong?

Comment: which version of android sdk are you using?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, "fragmentContainer" is not a fragment itself. Also, you can't replace static fragments with each other. They must be "dynamically added" fragments. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907673/android-cant-replace-one-fragment-with-another)

To replace dynamically created fragments, take a look at [this post](http://notionink.wikidot.com/rajeshbabu).

Comment: Yea, it's not. I know I can't replace fragments that are created in XML layouts. As I said, the fragment is dynamically added to a LinearLayout. Your second link isn't a SO post or neither it tells how to replace dynamically created fragments.

Comment: Sorry; the first link was an SO post, not the second.

Comment: Or possibly start by using the add() instead of replace().. (even though replace effectively removes child fragments)

Comment: Also, you can check fragment.isInLayout(). If this is true, then the fragment has already been added, and is perhaps not visible for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to replace the fragment whose ID is 'menuFragment'? If so then you cannot do this as any fragment specified in the XML layout cannot be replaced.

Comment: No I'm not. I'm trying to replace a dynamically added fragment inside the LinearLayout `fragmentContainer`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to replace the LinearLayout by FrameLayout?

please refer to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/gAhaoLlBob4 even though nobody explain why.

Comment: It doesn't have any effect. Why would it?

Comment: Looks this guy worked fine after change to FrameLayout
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019979/android-3-adding-a-fragment-to-a-linearlayout-fill-parent-does-not-work

Answer (score 0):

What version of Android are you targeting?

Try using the support fragment manager:

`FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: The minimum is 14 and the target is 17. Eclipse gives error if I try to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` method. For which level is it for?

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager is for API level 10 and lower, you shouldn't need it if your minimum is 14. Can you post more of your code? What does your fragment look like? I don't see anything wrong with the snippets you have posted.